# c++ Return input function

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a basic calculator and trying to produce a function which displays the main menu, takes user input and then returns the user input
here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int menu(int answer) {

    cout << "Options: \n";
    cout << "1. Addition \n";
    cout << "2. Subtraction \n";
    cout << "3. Division \n";
    cout << "4. Multiplication \n";

    cin >> answer;
    return answer;
}
int main() {
    int option;
    option = menu(option);
    switch (option) {
        //insert code here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `option = menu(option)` -- That call of `menu` does nothing to the parameter that is passed to it, `option`.  First, `option` is uninitialized, thus it makes no sense to pass it to a function (unless the function took a reference, which it doesn't).

Comment: that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: @thermo the general way to get a single return value from a function is to just return it, not to pass any parameters into it. If you need multiple values from a function (which you hopefully won't have to worry about for a little while, but it happens), then the technique is to either pass parameters by reference to the function (consult your text book index for "reference") or to return a `struct` or a `tuple`. General rule - if you pass a parameter to a function and the function doesn't use it, you don't need to pass it.

Comment: Hi @thermoplay and welcome to StackOverflow.
I'd like to note that StackOverflow is not a solve-my-homework website, it's a questions-and-answers website. ;) As the moderators haven't closed this post yet, I'd like to recommend you to describe what exactly you've tried and where exactly failed. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of how to ask the nice questions, and the [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) related to posts like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Just remove the parameter:

```
int menu() {

    int answer;

    cout << "Options: \n";
    cout << "1. Addition \n";
    cout << "2. Subtraction \n";
    cout << "3. Division \n";
    cout << "4. Multiplication \n";

    cin >> answer;
    return answer;
}

int main() {
    int option;
    option = menu();
    //...
}
```

**Option 2:**

Pass the variable by reference

```
void menu(int& answer) {

    cout << "Options: \n";
    cout << "1. Addition \n";
    cout << "2. Subtraction \n";
    cout << "3. Division \n";
    cout << "4. Multiplication \n";

    cin >> answer;
}

int main() {
    int option;
    menu(option);
    //...
}
```